# Problem regarding Cauchy's Theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and define $R_n(G) \subseteq G^n,R_n(G)=\{(g_1,g_2,...,g_n):g_1g_2...g_n=e\}$.

$1$. Show that the map $C:G^{n-1} \to R_n(G), C((g_1,g_2,...,g_{n-1}))=(g_1,g_2,...g_{n-1},(g_1g_2...g_{n-1})^{-1})$ is a bijection.

$2$. Let $\mathbb{Z}_n \times G^n \to G^n$ be the cyclic action of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ on $G^n$. Show that for $X \in R_n(G), [k]X \in R_n(G)$. Thus we have an action $\mathbb{Z}_n \times R_n(G) \to R_n(G)$.

My thought is this problem is related to the Cauchy's theorem but I don't know how to apply the theorem. I've spent an hour on it but I still got stuck at the beginning. I need help. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with Cauchy's theorem. Look at the action of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. What you need is that $g_1\cdot \dotsc \cdot g_{n-1}\cdot g_n = e$ implies $g_n \cdot g_1 \cdot \dotsc \cdot g_{n-1} = e$.

Comment: The relation between this problem and Cauchy's theorem is that you can use this problem to prove Cauchy's theorem. Not the other way round!